# Установить с/на example.com

Tags: предлоги

Внезапно возникло затруднение в выборе предлога. Контекст такой: пишу файл readme на GitHub, указываю в нём ссылку на сайт для установки стиля. С одной стороны, казалось бы, к глаголами "загрузить/установить/скачать" более уместно задать вопрос "откуда?" и использовать предлог "с", но с другой стороны, с глаголом "посмотреть" однозначно будет использован предлог "на". В данной же ситуации ссылка не прямая, т.е. установка происходит не сразу при переходе по ней. Вместо этого открывается сайт, на котором можно посмотреть информацию о стиле и скриншоты и там же установить его.

P.S. Если можно, ещё один вопрос не совсем по тематике сообщества - тот же предлог по-английски (Install on/from/at example.com).

Answer (score 1):

Сначала хочу обратить Ваше внимание на два момента.

Во-первых, Вы в одной фразе хотите очень много всего уместить.

Три действия, три глагола с разными предлогами:

- посмотреть/перейти на сайт
- скачать с сайта скрипт
- установить скрипт

Во-вторых, корректных вариантов итоговых формулировок может быть достаточно много. Вы озвучили лишь общий контекст задачи -- сложно понять, какие из формулировок вам подойдут. Можно конечно закидывать версии наудачу, авось какая-либо и понравится. Но я бы предпочёл посмотреть цельный фрагмент инструкции (несколько предложений до, несколько после).

Выше @ddbug сделал несколько своих предложений.

А мне, например, пришли в голову такие варианты:

- Перейти на [страницу установки скрипта](https://example.com) для загрузки и установки
- Скрипт с пользовательскими стилями можно скачать и установить с [сайта example.com](https://example.com)

P.S. Не бойтесь переформулировать мысль - и не упирайтесь в одну конкретную формулировку.

Answer (score 0):

Что если: "установите стиль согласно инструкциям на ..." или "откройте ссылку ... и выберите стиль из меню".

/* Про английский здесь спрашивать нельзя. Но если только быстро, между нами, по секрету - "at" вполне подойдёт. Английский очень гибок, за это его и полюбили программисты. В русском - много церемоний */

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял суть, то ***"подгрузить с/из" / "overload from"***. Если обязательно *install* (почему?!), то, может, *through/thru* За английский, впрочем, совсем не уверен, поскольку для меня эти вещи - из прошлой жизни.

PS Если честно, не очень понимаю, почему у вас вообще возникла идея с предлогом "на". "Посмотреть" - это "где", но никак не "откуда" и не "куда". Для вашей ситуации неприменимо, не говоря уж о том, что аналогия в отношении предлогов вещь опасная. Даже синонимичные глаголы могут требовать разных предлогов. Если уж так необходимо с чем-то сравнить, то глагол "выбрать" - где, "перенести" - откуда. Почему "посмотреть"-то? Или я все-таки не так вас понял?